# Authors get duplicated in Index

Tags: biblatex, indexing

I want to create an author index with `backend=bibtex` and `indexing=cite` using `biblatex`. However, some authors get duplicated when I have cited both `books` and `inproceedings` published by the same author.

In the following MWE, the author of both bibliographical entries gets listed twice although the author's name is identical:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{velemaWatChristelijkGereformeerd1947,
  langid = {Nederlands},
  location = {{Amsterdam}},
  title = {Wat is Christelijk Gereformeerd?},
  pagetotal = {151},
  publisher = {{Ds. H. Janssen-fonds}},
  date = {1947},
  author = {Velema, J.H.}}

@incollection{velemaKerkStrijd1992,
  location = {{Kampen}},
  title = {{{Kerk en strijd}}},
  booktitle = {{{Een eeuw christelijk-gereformeerd: aspecten van 100 jaar Christelijke Gereformeerde Kerken}}},
  publisher = {{Kok}},
  date = {1992},
  pages = {221-240},
  author = {Velema, J.H.},
  editor = {van 't Spijker, W. and Noorlandt, J.N. and van der Schaaf, H.},
  options = {useprefix=true}}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,indexing=cite,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\cite{velemaWatChristelijkGereformeerd1947,velemaKerkStrijd1992}

\printbibliography
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image: example index]

To merge the duplicated names in the index, I tried the solution provided in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/289518/189722) but that did not help. Could anyone provide an alternative solution to merge both names? Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful to see how these are shown in the `.idx` and `.ind` files.  I suspect that there's an extra space in one of them, or the spacing is different.  Of course, the problem then is to figure out why.

Comment: In the `.idx`file, the authors are indeed different: `\indexentry{Velema, J.H.}{1}` and `\indexentry{Velema, J.H.@Velema, J.H.}{1}`. In the `.ind file they end up identically: `\item Velema, J.H., 1` and `\item Velema, J.H., 1`. Of course, I can edit the `.idx` file manually to fix the problem, but it would be more convenient if it could be solved automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `biblatex` 3.13 contains a fix for https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/893 that is equivalent to the definition of `\mkbibindexname` (option 2) shown in the MWE below.
>
> Update your TeX distribution to obtain the current versions of `biblatex` and Biber.
>
> Further changes to the document should not be necessary.
>
> ```
> \documentclass{article}
>
> \usepackage[style=authoryear, indexing=cite, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
>
> \usepackage{filecontents}
> \begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
> @book{velemaWatChristelijkGereformeerd1947,
>   langid    = {dutch},
>   location  = {Amsterdam},
>   title     = {Wat is Christelijk Gereformeerd?},
>   pagetotal = {151},
>   publisher = {Ds.~H.~Janssen-fonds},
>   date      = {1947},
>   author    = {Velema, J. H.},
> }
> @incollection{velemaKerkStrijd1992,
>   location  = {Kampen},
>   title     = {Kerk en strijd},
>   booktitle = {Een eeuw christelijk-gereformeerd: aspecten van 100 jaar Christelijke Gereformeerde Kerken},
>   publisher = {Kok},
>   date      = {1992},
>   pages     = {221-240},
>   author    = {Velema, J. H.},
>   editor    = {van 't Spijker, W. and Noorlandt, J. N. and van der Schaaf, H.},
>   options   = {useprefix=true},
> }
> \end{filecontents*}
> \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
>
> \usepackage{makeidx}
> \makeindex
>
> \begin{document}
> \cite{velemaWatChristelijkGereformeerd1947,velemaKerkStrijd1992}
>
> \printbibliography
> \printindex
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> produces the expected result.
>
> The answer below is kept for historical interest.

As mentioned in the comments, the `.idx` file contains

```
\indexentry{Velema, J. H.}{1}
\indexentry{Velema, J. H.@Velema, J. H.}{1}
```

The index then ends up with two entries for J. H. Velema, one for `Velema, J. H.` and one for `Velema, J. H.@Velema, J. H.`.

The different entries are caused by `biblatex`'s name indexing settings. The relevant bits can be found in `biblatex.def` ([ll. 1166-1187](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/476a0dad3146012955b1f1441ffbc8f1d015ef35/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L1166-L1187))

```
\newcommand*{\mkbibindexname}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\ifdefvoid{#3}{}{#3 }%
     \@firstofone #1% remove spurious braces
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{ #4}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{, #2}%
     \actualoperator
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\MakeCapital{#3} }%
     #1%
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{ #4}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{, #2}}
    {\@firstofone #1% remove spurious braces
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{ #4}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
       {}
       {,}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{ #2}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{ #3}}}
```

If `useprefix` is true, `biblatex` will use `\actualoperator` (i.e. `@`) to make sure that the prefix is sorted correctly but shown in the expected capitalisation. But the `@` is also added in cases where it is not needed since there is no prefix.

The entry `velemaKerkStrijd1992` has an explicit `useprefx=true`, while `velemaWatChristelijkGereformeerd1947` uses the default `useprefix=false` setting. Hence, the former produces `Velema, J. H.@Velema, J. H.` and the latter `Velema, J. H.` for the index.

There are at least two possible solutions.

1. Enable `useprefix=true` globally and not only for `velemaKerkStrijd1992`. Then both entries will send `Velema, J. H.@Velema, J. H.` to the index.
2. Redefine `\mkbibndexname` to only use `\actualoperator` when necessary.

The MWE demonstrates option 2.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, indexing=cite, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\mkbibindexname}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\ifdefvoid{#3}{}{#3 }% 
     \@firstofone #1% remove spurious braces
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{ #4}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{, #2}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{%
       \actualoperator
       \MakeCapital{#3} %
       #1%
       \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{ #4}%
       \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{, #2}}}
    {\@firstofone #1% remove spurious braces
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{ #4}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
       {}
       {,}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{ #2}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{ #3}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{velemaWatChristelijkGereformeerd1947,
  langid    = {dutch},
  location  = {Amsterdam},
  title     = {Wat is Christelijk Gereformeerd?},
  pagetotal = {151},
  publisher = {Ds.~H.~Janssen-fonds},
  date      = {1947},
  author    = {Velema, J. H.},
}
@incollection{velemaKerkStrijd1992,
  location  = {Kampen},
  title     = {Kerk en strijd},
  booktitle = {Een eeuw christelijk-gereformeerd: aspecten van 100 jaar Christelijke Gereformeerde Kerken},
  publisher = {Kok},
  date      = {1992},
  pages     = {221-240},
  author    = {Velema, J. H.},
  editor    = {van 't Spijker, W. and Noorlandt, J. N. and van der Schaaf, H.},
  options   = {useprefix=true},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\cite{velemaWatChristelijkGereformeerd1947,velemaKerkStrijd1992}

\printbibliography
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Note how I changed `langid = {Nederlands},` to `langid = {dutch},` since `langid` takes `babel` language names as values. I also removed excess braces in some fields.

Comment: See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/893

Comment: Dear moewe, thank you very much! I can confirm that both solutions are working. Thank you also for fixing this by adding a commit on github. My question is solved.